# How to change how long notifications stay on a Mac?

Tags: macos, notifications

I have a webpage that will display notifications to OS X's notification (system notifications).  But it will disappear in 10 to 15 seconds.  Is there a way to change how long it stays?  (and what about change to not disappear at all?)

I found several pages dated 2014, which suggested using

```
defaults write com.apple.notificationcenterui bannerTime 60
```

or use `3` instead to make it 3 seconds. But this method doesn't work for my Mavericks and El Capitan OS X.

Comment: Is this different than https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/269006/how-can-i-change-banner-notification-time-on-a-macbook-with-os-x-10-10-5?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

I was able to get this to work as of Catalina (10.15.2)

First, you need to specify `-int` before the number of seconds parameter:

```
defaults write com.apple.notificationcenterui bannerTime -int 2
```

You then need to restart the NotificationCenter process by signing out/rebooting or running:

```
killall NotificationCenter
```

Answer (score 3):

On newer os, you can’t change this.

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/269022/5472

On older os, you can customize the timing:

```
defaults write com.apple.notificationcenterui bannerTime 2
```

Works for me on El Capitan.