# How can I change banner notification time on a MacBook with OS X 10.10.5?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, notifications

How can I go about changing the time that a banner notification stays on the screen before disappearing?

I did some research and tried the suggestion found [here](http://www.defaults-write.com/notification-center-change-banners-display-time/), but am having no success on my MacBook Air. I restarted and logged in/out of my account a few times after re-entering the command with no luck. Does this command no longer work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot easily customize the time anymore on current os since the preference has been removed since MacOS 10.10 Yosemite.

If you want your notifications to stay on the screen until you dismiss them, you can do the following:

Go to
System Preferences > Notifications

Select the notifications you want not to be dismissed automatically. Change the "alert style" to "Alerts" instead of "Banners".

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe @oa-'s answer is correct.

I am running Catalina (10.15.2) and was able to get a slightly modified method to what is mentioned in the link from OP working just fine.

First, you need to specify `-int` before the number of seconds parameter:

```
defaults write com.apple.notificationcenterui bannerTime -int 2
```

Otherwise, it's written as a string which won't be recognized as valid argument for the number seconds.

Before it'll take effect, you'll also need to restart the NotificationCenter process by signing out/in or running:

```
killall NotificationCenter
```

Comment: @oa- is right, this defaults option doesn't work anymore. I tried set it 10 but there's no difference at all. macOS version: 10.13.6.

Comment: according this, for macOS 10.13 and below you need to leave out the "-int" flag from my example above as only 10.14 and later require it: https://osxdaily.com/2014/01/29/change-notifications-banner-time-mac-os-x/

Comment: It doesn't matter if the `-int` is added or not. This very setting `bannerTime` is removed. This could be also confirmed by the comments from the link you provided.

Comment: here is proof of it working on my system (10.15). I use it to change the `bannerTime` to 1 second and then to 10 seconds successfully: https://i.imgur.com/Dqn3dKx.mp4

Comment: Thx for ur illustration. I tried it again with the same test from ur video. I also did `killall NotificationCenter`. It just doesn't work on 10.13. Shit. No matter with or without `-int`, the display time is unchanged. Sorry about the downvoting, I'm not able to revert it now.

Comment: I got it. `defaults -currentHost write` works for me. Cause some settings for Notification is set from the System Preferences as the same with using `-currentHost`, to make `bannerTime` work, I need to set it with `-currentHost` as well. Otherwise it won't take effect. Another solution is to remove all the `-currentHost` settings, and set everything without `-currentHost`.