# Is there a way to change the notification time for High Sierra or Mojave?

Tags: high-sierra, mojave, notifications

Found an old solution, but it doesn't work anymore:
http://osxdaily.com/2014/01/29/change-notifications-banner-time-mac-os-x/

This also doesn't work and only works on older OS:
[How to change how long notifications stay on a Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/249505/how-to-change-how-long-notifications-stay-on-a-mac)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  If an old question need a new answer, we generally don’t open a new thread and instead update or add to the old answer section. If your situation is different than the one linked, of course edit the details in the body of the question above and the hold / duplicate can be reviewed. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/269006/how-can-i-change-banner-notification-time-on-a-macbook-with-os-x-10-10-5?rq=1

Comment: This answer needed an edit https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/269022/5472 - the short answer is no, you can’t change the time but you can allow them to persist.